# When user types their username in a txtbox the software crashes

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

Currently I'm trying to create a login system where the user signs up to the program and creates there own user name and password, this user name and password will then be saved on a SQL database this part works fine, however, the part where they use this username and password to login to the system isn't working and what I'm attempting to do is check if the username in the textbox is the same as one of the usernames in the database here is the code and thank you for your support.

```
Imports System
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb
Imports System.Data.SqlClient
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.ComponentModel
Imports System.Drawing
Imports System.Linq
Imports System.Text
Imports System.Threading.Tasks
Public Class Form1

    Dim Array(100)

    Private Sub BtnSignUp_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnSignUp.Click
        Dim con As SqlConnection
        Dim Insert As SqlCommand
   
        con = New SqlConnection("Data Source=DESKTOP-4U5G5M4;Initial Catalog=Profile;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False")
        con.Open()
        Insert = New SqlCommand("INSERT INTO EmployeeProfile (item_title) VALUES('" + TxtFirst.Text + "')", con)

        Insert.ExecuteNonQuery()
        con.Close() 
    End Sub






   Private Sub BtnLoginSQL_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles BtnLoginSQL.Click
    Dim Correct As Boolean = False
    Dim Pass As Boolean = False
    Dim Slc As New SqlCommand("", con)
    con.Open()
   
    Slc.CommandText = "SELECT item_title FROM EmployeeProfile"    
 
    If Slc.ExecuteScalar = TxtUsername.Text Then

        Correct = True

    End If

    If Correct = True And TxtUsername.Text = Nothing Then
        Correct = False
    End If

    If Correct = True Then
        PnlPersonInfo.Visible = False
        PnlLogin.Visible = False
        PnlHome.Visible = True
    End If
    con.Close()

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: You failed to mention your love of whitespace when introducing yourself :) in future try and keep your code as concise as possible.

Comment: You solve this sort of problem by debugging... we can't read over your code and easily spot what is wrong. But you can step through on a debugger and catch where it crashes very easily. If you are still stuck then, post the additional info and maybe someone can help.

Comment: You've dumped far too much code into this post. You have incomplete methods, commented code, and a lot of code that has nothing to do with your problem. Please see [ask] and [mre], and reduce the code to the **absolute minimum** needed to demonstrate the problem.

Comment: Ill simplify the post right now sorry

Comment: While updating your post, maybe add in the exception you get and exactly where you get it

Comment: Sorry ill re edit to show you the exception

Comment: Your select SQL is invalid...  and should be using a parameter, and your connection should be inside a using block (assuming VB has those). And you are selecting based on the username, without the password? Big security hole.

Comment: This `Slc.CommandText = ("SELECT * FROM EmployeeProfile (item_title) VALUES (" + TxtUsername.Text + ")")` is an invalid select statement

Comment: I thought that was the case, do you guys know where i could potentially find information on valid select statements.

Comment: Seriously? Have you tried google? There are 100's of tutorials out there...

Comment: Yes i have and i keep receiving the same errors. also i just want to thank everyone for helping me so far

Comment: You can find information about valid SQL SELECT statements in any SQL tutorial. You have more problems in the code you've posted other than the invalid SELECT, though. `Reader.Read()` returns a boolean that indicates whether the read was successful or not, so it will never be equal to the username. You check for the textbox value being empty after you've already used it to query the database (in your invalid SELECT).

Comment: You can (and should) always try the [official documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

Comment: Yikes, this looks scary-vulnerable to sql injection issues.

Comment: @DaleK Yes, the official documentation is always good but in this case I think it might make the OP quit programming. That particular document would be very hard for a beginner to read.

Comment: Hi all i just want to first thank you again for the support and all the links you all have sent, which are pure gold by the way and have helped me almost solve this problem. However,  I'm still stuck on one last thing which is making it identify all rows in the column currently it only identifies the first row in the second column i understand that its because I'm using ExecuteScalar but I'm not sure what to use exactly, again thank you for all the support.

Comment: Hi everyone i just wanted to Thank You for helping me solve my problem which is now solved and for helping me in future through the documentation you have all sent me :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your application doesn't crash when the user types in the name. I crashes when he clicks the button.

```
Dim con As SqlConnection
con.Open()
```

Exception-(System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. con was Nothing.)

You have only given your variable a datatype. This a connection is an object and must be created. The `New` keyword will call the constructor of the connection.

```
 Dim con As New SqlConnection()
```

Of course, you wouldn't be able to open it without a connection string. Also, you shouldn't open it until directly before an `.Execute`... method.

Here is a tiny tutorial on Select queries. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-select-query.htm

You should always use parameters to avoid Sql injection. Look up parameters in sql.

Connections need to be closed and disposed. Look up Using...End Using blocks to accomplish this.

Then try again and if you have more problems, ask again with your new code.

Comment: Hi @Mary i put 'Slc.CommandText' after' con.open' just because i wasn't sure if i needed to for the execute to work. Also i was just wondering if you knew which execute would select all columns, if not thank you any way for the advise :)

Comment: @JoshuaManicolo `con.Open` should be directly before the `.Execute...` line. Connections are precious objects and should only be open for the shortest amount of time.

Comment: @JoshuaManicolo For quick and dirty you can use `Select * From` but in production code always list the names of the columns you want to retrieve.